# Kafka Connect Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 2 error(s): Invalid value ... could not be found

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, strimzi

I'm trying to make use of [Schema Registry Transfer SMT plugin](https://github.com/OneCricketeer/schema-registry-transfer-smt) but I get following error.

```
PUT /connectors/kafka-connector-sb-16-sb-16/config returned 400 (Bad Request): Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 2 error(s):
      Invalid value cricket.jmoore.kafka.connect.transforms.SchemaRegistryTransfer for configuration transforms.AvroSchemaTransfer.type: Class cricket.jmoore.kafka.connect.transforms.SchemaRegistryTransfer could not be found.
      Invalid value null for configuration transforms.AvroSchemaTransfer.type: Not a Transformation
      You can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint `/connector-plugins/{connectorType}/config/validate`
```

I use strimzi operator to manage my kafka objects in kubernetes.

Kafka Connect config:

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: KafkaConnect
metadata:
  name: {{.Release.Name}}-{{.Values.ENVNAME}}
  annotations:
    strimzi.io/use-connector-resources: "true"
  labels:
    app: {{.Release.Name}}
  #  owner: {{ .Values.owner | default "NotSet" }}
  #  branch: {{ .Values.branch | default "NotSet" | trunc 56 | trimSuffix "-" }}
spec:
  logging:
    type: inline
    loggers:
      connect.root.logger.level: "DEBUG"
  template:
    pod:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: wecapacrdev001-azurecr-io-pull-secret
      metadata:
        annotations:
          prometheus.io/path: /metrics
          prometheus.io/port: "9404"
          prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
              - matchExpressions:
                  - key: kubernetes.io/arch
                    operator: In
                    values:
                      - arm64
  authentication:
    type: scram-sha-512
    username: {{.Values.ENVNAME}}
    passwordSecret:
      secretName: {{.Values.ENVNAME}}
      password: password
  bootstrapServers: {{.Values.ENVNAME}}-kafka-bootstrap:9093
  tls:
    trustedCertificates:
      - secretName: {{.Values.ENVNAME}}-cluster-ca-cert
        certificate: ca.crt
  config:
    group.id: {{.Values.ENVNAME}}-connect-cluster
    offset.storage.topic: {{.Values.ENVNAME}}-connect-cluster-offsets
    config.storage.topic: {{.Values.ENVNAME}}-connect-cluster-configs
    status.storage.topic: {{.Values.ENVNAME}}-connect-cluster-status
    config.storage.replication.factor: -1
    offset.storage.replication.factor: -1
    status.storage.replication.factor: -1
    key.converter: org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter
    value.converter: org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter
  image: capcr.azurecr.io/devops/kafka:0.27.1-kafka-2.8.0-arm64-v2.7
  jvmOptions:
    -Xms: 3g
    -Xmx: 3g
  livenessProbe:
    initialDelaySeconds: 30
    timeoutSeconds: 15
  metricsConfig:
    type: jmxPrometheusExporter
    valueFrom:
      configMapKeyRef:
        key: metrics-config.yml
        name: {{.Release.Name}}-{{.Values.ENVNAME}}
  readinessProbe:
    initialDelaySeconds: 300
    timeoutSeconds: 15
  replicas: 3
  resources:
    limits:
      cpu: 1000m
      memory: 4Gi
    requests:
      cpu: 100m
      memory: 3Gi
```

Connector config:

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: KafkaConnector
metadata:
  name: {{.Release.Name}}-{{.Values.ENVNAME}}
  labels:
    strimzi.io/cluster: kafka-connect-cluster-{{.Values.ENVNAME}}
    app: {{.Release.Name}}
    #  owner: {{ .Values.owner | default "NotSet" }}
    #  branch: {{ .Values.branch | default "NotSet" | trunc 56 | trimSuffix "-" }}
spec:
  class: org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector
  config:
    offset-syncs.topic.replication.factor: "3"
    refresh.topics.interval.seconds: "60"
    replication.factor: "3"
    key.converter: org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter
    value.converter: org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter
    source.cluster.alias: SPLITTED
    source.cluster.auto.commit.interval.ms: "3000"
    source.cluster.auto.offset.reset: earliest
    source.cluster.bootstrap.servers: {{.Values.ENVNAME}}-kafka-bootstrap:9093
    source.cluster.fetch.max.bytes: "60502835"
    source.cluster.group.id: {{.Values.ENVNAME}}-mirroring
    source.cluster.max.poll.records: "100"
    source.cluster.max.request.size: "60502835"
    source.cluster.offset.storage.topic: {{.Values.ENVNAME}}-connect-cluster-offsets
    source.cluster.config.storage.topic: {{.Values.ENVNAME}}-connect-cluster-configs
    source.cluster.status.storage.topic: {{.Values.ENVNAME}}-connect-cluster-status
    source.cluster.producer.compression.type: gzip
    source.cluster.replica.fetch.max.bytes: "60502835"
    source.cluster.sasl.jaas.config: org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule
      required username="{{.Values.ENVNAME}}" password="{{.Values.kafka.password}}";
    source.cluster.sasl.mechanism: SCRAM-SHA-512
    source.cluster.security.protocol: SASL_SSL
    source.cluster.ssl.keystore.location: /opt/kafka/keystore/kafka_keystore.p12
    source.cluster.ssl.keystore.password: password
    source.cluster.ssl.keystore.type: PKCS12
    source.cluster.ssl.truststore.location: /opt/kafka/keystore/kafka_keystore.p12
    source.cluster.ssl.truststore.password: password
    source.cluster.ssl.truststore.type: PKCS12
    sync.topic.acls.enabled: "false"
    target.cluster.alias: AGGREGATED
    target.cluster.auto.commit.interval.ms: "3000"
    target.cluster.auto.offset.reset: earliest
    target.cluster.bootstrap.servers: {{.Values.ENVNAME}}-kafka-bootstrap:9093
    target.cluster.fetch.max.bytes: "60502835"
    target.cluster.group.id: {{.Values.ENVNAME}}-test
    target.cluster.max.poll.records: "100"
    target.cluster.max.request.size: "60502835"
    target.cluster.offset.storage.topic: {{.Values.ENVNAME}}-connect-cluster-offsets
    target.cluster.config.storage.topic: {{.Values.ENVNAME}}-connect-cluster-configs
    target.cluster.status.storage.topic: {{.Values.ENVNAME}}-connect-cluster-status
    target.cluster.producer.compression.type: gzip
    target.cluster.replica.fetch.max.bytes: "60502835"
    target.cluster.sasl.jaas.config: org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule
      required username="{{.Values.ENVNAME}}" password="{{.Values.kafka.password}}";
    target.cluster.sasl.mechanism: SCRAM-SHA-512
    target.cluster.security.protocol: SASL_SSL
    target.cluster.ssl.keystore.location: /opt/kafka/keystore/kafka_keystore.p12
    target.cluster.ssl.keystore.password: password
    target.cluster.ssl.keystore.type: PKCS12
    target.cluster.ssl.truststore.location: /opt/kafka/keystore/kafka_keystore.p12
    target.cluster.ssl.truststore.password: password
    target.cluster.ssl.truststore.type: PKCS12
    tasks.max: "4"
    topics: ^topic-to-be-replicated$
    topics.blacklist: ""
    transforms: AvroSchemaTransfer
    transforms.AvroSchemaTransfer.dest.schema.registry.url: http://schemaregistry-{{.Values.ENVNAME}}-cp-schema-registry:8081
    transforms.AvroSchemaTransfer.src.schema.registry.url: http://schemaregistry-{{.Values.ENVNAME}}-cp-schema-registry:8081
    transforms.AvroSchemaTransfer.transfer.message.keys: "false"
    transforms.AvroSchemaTransfer.type: cricket.jmoore.kafka.connect.transforms.SchemaRegistryTransfer
    transforms.TopicRename.regex: (.*)
    transforms.TopicRename.replacement: replica.$1
    transforms.TopicRename.type: org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter
  tasksMax: 4
```

I tried to build the plugin and build the docker image like described [here](https://strimzi.io/docs/operators/latest/full/deploying.html#creating-new-image-from-base-str):

```
ARG STRIMZI_BASE_IMAGE=0.29.0-kafka-3.1.1-arm64
FROM quay.io/strimzi/kafka:$STRIMZI_BASE_IMAGE
USER root:root
COPY schema-registry-transfer-smt/target/schema-registry-transfer-smt-0.2.1.jar /opt/kafka/plugins/
USER 1001
```

I can see in logs that the plugin is loaded

```
INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/opt/kafka/plugins/schema-registry-transfer-smt-0.2.1.jar} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader) [main]
INFO Loading plugin from: /opt/kafka/plugins/schema-registry-transfer-smt-0.2.1.jar (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader) [main]
DEBUG Loading plugin urls: [file:/opt/kafka/plugins/schema-registry-transfer-smt-0.2.1.jar] (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader) [main]
```

However, when I execute `kubectl describe KafkaConnect ...`, I get following status which probably means the plugin is not loaded.

```
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2022-10-31T07:22:43.749290Z
    Status:                True
    Type:                  Ready
  Connector Plugins:
    Class:              org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector
    Type:               sink
    Version:            2.8.0
    Class:              org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceConnector
    Type:               source
    Version:            2.8.0
    Class:              org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorCheckpointConnector
    Type:               source
    Version:            1
    Class:              org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorHeartbeatConnector
    Type:               source
    Version:            1
    Class:              org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector
    Type:               source
    Version:            1
```

The logs prints classpath `jvm.classpath = ...` and it doesn't "include schema-registry-transfer-smt-0.2.1.jar".

This look like configuration error. I tried to create and use fat jar, compile with java11, change scope of provided dependencies and many more. The repository's last commit was created in 2019. Does it make sense to bump all dependency versions? The error message doesn't suggest that.